# Как обновить DataGrid.ItemsSource без фризов (C# WPF .NET 4.5)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Приветствую всех, увы попытки найти 'велосипеды' в гугле закончились безрезультатно.
Проблема такова:

У меня есть

```
public static DataTable DataTableAccounts { get; set; }
```

Который я получаю с БД

Чтоб впервые отобразить его в своем DataGrid я делаю так:

```
DataGridAccounts.ItemsSource = DataTableAccounts.DefaultView;
```

Потом я начинаю проводить 'некие манипуляции' с DataTableAccounts
и чтоб отобразить измененную версию, я использую костыль:

```
DataGridAccounts.ItemsSource = null;
DataGridAccounts.ItemsSource = DataTableAccounts.DefaultView;
```

**Все работает отлично, НО** обновляю довольно часто, примерно раза 2 в сек. а DataTableAccounts большой (1000 рядов)
**Поэтому у меня все во фризах.**

**Вопрос такой:
Как асинхронно (либо с помощью других триксов) обновлять DataGrid без фризов?**

P.S. Я пытался и через Binding в разметке, но тогда ничего не обновляется=)

Comment: Никак. Расскажите нам про свои манипуляции - проблема явно где-то в них...

Comment: Через привязку `ObservableCollection` и ее обновление, пробовали?

Comment: @Bulson , https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0336be12-6d39-4cfa-8586-c987954e0010/binding-on-datagrid-with-observablecollection?forum=wpf  по такому примеру?

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/14.2.php) нормальный пример.

Answer (score 2):

Ну по поводу фризов это логично. Когда систему заставляют перерисовываться два раза в секунду, для не самого быстрого грида это напряжно.
Отсюда текущий вариант реализации будет тормозить в любом случае.
Варианты решения: для текущей ситуации надо проверить что включена виртуализация ячеек у грида: EnableRowVirtualization="True", данное позволяет перерисовывать только отображаемые ячейки, скорее всего это поможет.
В противном случае (да и вообще если делать по человечески)) придется думать как уменьшить число обновлений страницы. А вот тут без общего кода (как проходят манипуляции) ничего не сделать.
Но общую направленность могу подсказать. ItemSource привязывает грид к коллекции. Соответсвенно при изменении коллекции меняются значения грида. Проблема в том, что метод: DefaultView, каждый раз генерирует новую, автономную, коллекцию, которая не связанна с основными данными. Следовательно надо сделать общую коллекцию, привязать к ней грид, и в коде редактировать(!) эту коллекцию). Жизнь станет проще.

Comment: Я 'наговнокодил', только из-за того, что мне нужно видеть изменения в БД в реальном времени, поэтому приходится так часто обновлять DataGrid, т.к. изменения в БД производиться из более 50 потоков.  Пытался делать привязку через Binding, но почему-то вообще не работает.

Comment: Вы очень полезную мысль написали. Т.е. я могу привязать DataGrid к переменной колекции, которая уже обновляется методом DataTableAccounts.DefaultView; Но пока еще не догоняю в деталях

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `ObservableCollection`. Все действия, что происходят в коллекции, будут сразу отображаться в `DataGrid` и обнулять ничего не придётся.